# Question about Szilard paper : why does he say entropy decreases during expansion?

Tags: thermodynamics, information

I am reading Szilard paper : http://www.sns.ias.edu/~tlusty/courses/InfoInBio/Papers/Szilard1929.pdf

I don't understand some of the things he says.

During the isothermal expansion of the gas, he says that the entropy decreases, but I don't understand why.

Indeed, for me during this expansion the gas received positive heat and gives work. Thus as the heat received is positive, the entropy variation should be positive ?

He says this on end of page 127 beginning of 128, around equation (4) :

> The decrease of entropy
>   equals the ratio of the quantity of heat taken
>   from the heat reservoir during the isothermal
>   expansion, to the temperature of the heat
>   reservoir in question

The gas receives a **positive** heat during the expansion, so the entropy should **increase**.

I don't want any modern explanation, I would like to understand how he thought with his knowledge at the time (I know that we can understand the Szilard engine with information correlation to a memory)

Comment: It looks like Szilard is considering a very special case involving only a _single_ molecule in a chamber. Hence the usual ideal gas results might not hold.

Comment: @knzhou the gas being single molecule or not we still have $W+Q=0$ here. As we push the piston we have $Q>0$

Comment: Given the discussion and how the signs are defined, it seems to follow quite naturally. I think you need to read the early parts of the paper more closely to follow just how Szilard is defining S and what it is relative to.

Answer (score 0):

The total entropy in the cylinder-heat bath system decreases for the following reason: the cylinder is heated (in other words, entropy is transferred into the cylinder from the heat bath, as you note), but the energy transferred during the heating process is extracted in the form of reversible work (which carries no entropy). The conditions before and after inserting and moving the piston are identical (namely, the single molecule explores the entire cylinder at temperature $T$). Thus, in the thought experiment, some amount of entropy in the cylinder-heat bath system is destroyed. Szilard's task is to investigate how entropy is generated in the process of knowing where, when, and how to move the piston to examine whether the Second Law still stands regarding the total entropy in the universe.